# Lemma 10.16 Rudin's functional analysis.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

> **Lemma 10.16** Suppose $V$ and $W$ are open sets in some topological space $X$, $V \subset W$ and $W$ contains no boundary point of $V$. Then $V$ is the union of components of $W$
> (Recall that a component of $W$ is , by definition, a maximal connected subset of $W$.

> **Proof**. Let $\Omega$ be a component of $W$ that intersects $V$. Let $U$ be the complement of $\overline{V}$. Since $W$ contains no boundary point of $V$, $\Omega$ is the union of the two disjoint open sets $\Omega \cap V$ and$\Omega \cap U$. Since $\Omega$ is connected then $\Omega \cap U$ is empty. Thus $\Omega \subset V$.

Can anyone elaborate on how exactly the fact that $W \cap \partial V = \emptyset$ is used?
My only clue was to write $\partial V = \overline{V} - V$ but I cannot manage to reach a contradiction assuming $W \cap U \neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

We always have $\Omega=(\Omega\cap V)\cup (\Omega\cap \partial V)\cup (\Omega \cap (\overline{V})^c)$. The first term stays as is, the second term is empty because $\Omega\cap \partial V\subset W\cap \partial V=\emptyset$ by hypothesis; and the last term is $\Omega\cap U$ by definition. Therefore, $\Omega= (\Omega\cap V)\cup (\Omega \cap U)$.